# FireFox 4 - Is it possible to disable the left and right arrows at either end of the tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, mouse-wheel

I always use the wheel on my mouse to scroll back and forth along my open tags.

I was wondering if there was some way to hide the arrows at either end to free up a bit more space for viewing tabs.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire UI of Firefox is styleable using CSS – either by editing [`userChrome.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) or through the [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/stylish) extension.

#### With Stylish:

1. Install [the Stylish extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) for Firefox.
2. Install [this userstyle](http://userstyles.org/styles/45330/firefox-tab-bar-hide-scroll-buttons?r=1300402765).

#### With `userChrome`:

1. Read [this page about userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css).
2. Go to your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder). Then go to the `chrome` folder there, creating it if necessary.
3. In the `chrome` folder, create a plain text file named `userChrome.css`.
4. The style you need is:

   ```
   tabbrowser toolbarbutton[class^="scrollbutton"],
   #TabsToolbar toolbarbutton[class^="scrollbutton"]
   {
       display: none !important;
   }
   ```
5. Save your changes and restart Firefox.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Only niggles are that pinned tabs overlap the firefox button slightly, and that the space is still left between pinned tabs and rest of the tabs where the left arrow used to be. **Edit:** Actually, that only seems to happen when you preview the style while you have some pinned tabs! It's perfect!